# Typescript node throw syntax error on 'as' keyword

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm in the process of creating a React v16 app with Redux v4 and Typescript v2.7.  I'm having an odd issue where [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node), that I use to run my tests, exhibits different behavior than [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader), that I use to build and run my project.

It's specifically around a particular instance of the `as` keyword.  This is complicated further by the fact that I'm using a version of redux-thunk that currently resides in [a pull request](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/pull/180) in order to allow redux-thunk to support Redux v4 with Typescript.

Running `ts-node scirpt.ts` on

*script.ts:*

```
require("babel-register")({
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
})

require('configureStore')
```

*configureStore.ts:*

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk, { ThunkAction, ThunkMiddleware } from 'redux-thunk'

type MyState = {foo: number}
type MyAction = {type: "foo"}

function myReducer(state: MyState, action: MyAction) {
  return state
}

function configureStore(state: MyState) {
  const store = createStore(
    myReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<MyState, MyAction>),
  )
  return store
}
```

generates the following error:

```
SyntaxError: configureStore.ts: Unexpected token, expected , (14:26)
  12 |   const store = createStore(
  13 |     myReducer,
> 14 |     applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<MyState, MyAction>),
     |                           ^
  15 |   )
  16 |   return store
  17 | }
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:1749:33)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseCallExpressionArguments (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3564:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseSubscripts (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3533:31)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3504:15)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\dev\js-starter-kit\node_modules\babylon\lib\index.js:3344:19)
```

The fact that it's a *syntax* error really confuses me.  It makes me feel like it's some issue with ts-node?  Because that same exact code runs fine with webpack and awesome-typescript-loader.

Also, if you put all this code in the same file and don't `require` one from the other, the issue **does not happen!!**  That doesn't make any sense to me.

`ts-node --version` returns the following:

```
ts-node v5.0.1
node v6.10.3
typescript v2.7.2
```

The problem as described here is reduced as far as I could get it, but if it's helpful, I've published a `testsFail` branch [here](https://github.com/zposten/react-starter-kit/tree/testsFail) on the project I'm working on where the issue originates from.  To see it, clone the project, check out the `testsFail` branch, and run `npm install`.  Then replace `node_modules/redux-thunk/index.d.ts` with [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Cryrivers/redux-thunk/master/index.d.ts) from the aforementioned pull request. And finally run `npm test` to see the error.  If you go to the previous commit, the tests will pass but `npm start` will fail.

Can some brilliant person out there shed some light on this for me?
Thank you in advance for any help!